# Symfony 4, get the root path of the project from a custom class (not a controller class)

Tags: php, symfony4

In the src/Utils directory, I created a custom class **Foo** for various things. I'm looking for a way to get the absolute root path of the symfony 4 project

From a controller, its easy with :

```
$webPath = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();
```

But from a custom class I created in my src/Utils directory, how can I get the root path directory ?

I could pass the path from the controller to the **Foo** class :

```
$webPath = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();
$faa = new Foo($webPath);
$faa->doSomething();
```

but I think its more proper to store this information in the Foo class and have only "controller logic" in the controller class

Comment: Pass this value as parameter to Foo class __constructor__ which will be autowired.

Comment: Hmmm, is it possible to provide me an example with the construct method ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In Symfony `AppKernel` class is handling the project root directory under method `getProjectDir()`. To get it in the controller you can do:

```
$projectRoot = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();
```

it will return you a project root directory.

If you need the project root directory in one of your classes you have two choices which I will present to you. First is passing `AppKernel` as dependency:

```
class Foo 
{
    /** KernelInterface $appKernel */
    private $appKernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $appKernel)
    {
        $this->appKernel = $appKernel;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Symfony 4 autowiring dependencies it will be autmomaticaly injeted into your class and you could access it by doing:

```
$this->appKernel->getProjectDir();
```

But **please notice**: I don't think it's a good idea, until you have real need and more to do with `AppKernel` class than getting the project root dir. Specially if you think later on creating about unit tests for your class. You would automatically increase complexity by having a need to create mock of `AppKernel` for example.

Second option and IMHO better would be to pass only a string with path to directory. You could achieve this by defining a service inside `config/services.yaml` like this:

```
services:
    (...)
    MyNamespace\Foo:
        arguments:
            - %kernel.project_dir%
```

and your constructor would look like:

```
class Foo 
{
    /** string $rootPath */
    private $rootPath;

    public function __construct(string $rootPath)
    {
        $this->rootPath = $rootPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the very first explanation you should also mention to include `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;` above the class file.

Comment: `config/services.yaml and $rootPath` are good idea instead of `KernelInterface`

Answer (score 35):

Without `Kernel` injection

`config/services.yaml`

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        bind:
            $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

....

```
class Foo
{
    private $projectDir;

    public function __construct(string $projectDir)
    {
        $this->projectDir = $projectDir;
    }
}
```

Comment: solution in the official doc : 
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-important-deprecations

Answer (score 27):

**If your class is extending:**
`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`, then you can get the root dir as

```
$projectRoot = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
```

**or**

**Inject `ContainerBagInterface` to your controller**

```
protected $projectRoot;

public function __construct(ContainerBagInterface $containerBag)
{
    $this->projectRoot = $containerBag->get('kernel.project_dir');;
}
```

**or**

**Even better and the recommended approach**

Inject the `root_dir` to your `Foo` class. Add the following to your config under services

```
services:
    foo:
        class:     App\Path\To\Foo
        arguments: ['%kernel.project_dir%']
```

The container should pass the argument to your class on resolving, the `Foo` class should look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Path\To;

class Foo {

  private $projectDir;

  public function __construct($projectDir) 
  {
     $this->projectDir = $projectDir;
  }
}
```

Comment: In 2019/2020/2021, with current versions of Symfony (4,5+) this is the way to do this.

Comment: The last example worked great for me. However, I had to change `%kernel.root_dir%` to `%kernel.project_dir%`.

Answer (score 8):

This is work :

```
// from Foo class
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
...
class Foo{
    private $rootDir;
    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->rootDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();
    }
    public function myfoomethod(){
        return $this->getRootDir();
    }
    public function getRootDir(){
        return $this->rootDir;
    }
}


// from the controller class 
use App\Utils\Foo;
...
class FaaController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/scenario", name="scenario")
     */
    public function new(Foo $foo)
    {
        dump($foo->myfoomethod()); //show the dir path !
        return $this->render('faa/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you included the use statement tho

Comment: indeed, no other solution mentions  `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface` but nothing will work without it

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to do this without injecting useless dependencies, is to create an utility method like this (in my case it's in `src\Utils\Utils.php`):

```
namespace App\Utils;

public static function getRootDir(): string
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../..';
}
```

Then simply call it anywhere with

```
Utils::getRootDir()
```

It works on both Windows and Linux, but if you prefer you can use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `'/'`

---

Also, it's much more efficient than the `Kernel::getProjectDir()` method, which instantiates a `ReflectionObject` and then does a recursion until it finds the folder with composer.json, with multiple checks that involves I/O such as `is_file()`. Using the `__DIR__` costant is much better since its value is already available in memory, without the need to access the physical disk.

Comment: this is NOT USELESS dependencies, this is portability.