# How to get project directory from Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

What I need is the project directory or the public directory from symfony.

```
use App\Kernel;

class FileReader
{
    public function __construct(
       Kernel $kernel
    )
    {
        var_dump ($kernel->getProjectDir());

    }
}
```

The problem is I can not inject the kernel to my class.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850493/symfony-4-get-the-root-path-of-the-project-from-a-custom-class-not-a-controlle) post there are several strange things for me.

First, I get this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Utils\Lotto\FileReader": argument "$kernel" of method "__construct()" references class "App\Kernel" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to one of its parents: interface "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface", or interface "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface".

Second, I have no KernelInterface from PHPStorm autocomplete, those interface is only for HttpKernelInterface what has no `getProjectDirectory` method.

How can I read out the `/var/www/myproject` or `/var/www/myproject/public/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not inject your Kernel, but instead inject only what you need. In this case it is the project directory, available through your service definition in **config/services.yaml** with the parameter **%kernel.project_dir%**:

```
services:
    App\Utils\Lotto\FileReader:
        arguments:
            $projectDirectory: "%kernel.project_dir%"
```

Then adjust your class constructor:

```
public function __construct(string $projectDirectory) {
    $this->directory = $projectDirectory;
}
```

As a bonus, you could make the directory automatically available for all of your services by defining a global "bind" parameter:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $projectDirectory: "%kernel.project_dir%"
```

With that definition, every Service can use the variable $projectDirectory in its __construct() without the need to define it explicit.