# Symfony4: Image cannot be saved

Tags: php, symfony

I have updated from Symfony 3.4 to 4.0 and have verified the operation.  
The image save function says "Completed", but the image is not saved.  
Because the save destination was set to web/uploads,
In Image.php, I changed the image directory path from `web` to `public`, but it didn't change.  
Is there anything else I need to change?

ImageController.php

```php
    public function saveAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $imageService = $this->get("admin.imageService");
        if ($token === $imageService->getImageToken($staffId, $uniq)) {
            try {
                $imageService->saveImage($image);
                // Normal termination parameters #This is required for onComplete to fire on Mac OSX
                $msg = $this->container->getParameter('uploadify_success');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                $response->setStatusCode(400);
            }
        } else {
            $msg = 'Access is illegal.';
            $response->setStatusCode(400);
        }
        $response->send();
```

ImageService.php

```php
    public function saveImage(Image $image)
    {

        // Set the extension (already set when saving from an email attachment)
        $ext = $image->getImageExtension();
        if (!$ext && $image->getFileUpload()) {
            $ext = $image->getFileUpload()->guessExtension();
            $image->setImageExtension($ext);
        }

        // save
        $this->entityManager->persist($image);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
```

Image.php

```php
    private function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // Absolute path to the location to save the uploaded file
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../../../public/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the image directory name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads';
    }
```

**Postscript**

index.html.twig

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('uploadifive/jquery.uploadifive.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/image.five.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('uploadifive/uploadifive.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{# contentBody #}
{% block contentBody %}
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Hq/Image:manager')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

manager.html.twig

```
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <div class="operations">
                {{ form_start(form, {"attr": {"id": "uploadForm"}}) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.fileUpload) }}
                    {{ form_rest(form) }}
                {{ form_end(form) }}
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div id="fileQueue"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe this is a Symfony thing, but where is the code that actually uploads the file? Did you change the destination directory there, too?

Comment: @AkenRoberts I'm using uploadifive, but it seems that the save destination depends on the Symfony settings.

Comment: Can you check in your twig-template/the rendered html that `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is set?

Comment: @dbrumann No. There was no enctype setting. Just in case, I added the twig file, so please check it.

Comment: In order for FileUpload to work you must set the enctype on your form, e.g. by adding it to `{'attr': { 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}}` (I think). You can see it in this free video from SymfonyCasts: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-uploads/upload-request#multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

You should use `projectDir` istead of your `getUploadRootDir()` with hazardous `../../`

Take a look at this post [Symfony 4, get the root path of the project from a custom class (not a controller class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850493/symfony-4-get-the-root-path-of-the-project-from-a-custom-class-not-a-controlle/52851567) for the detailed instructions

New in Symfony 3.3 : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-a-simpler-way-to-get-the-project-root-directory